# plot bar chart for time series data based on factor value (1,0)

Tags: r, timeserieschart

I have a dataframe/tibble which looks likes:

```
z <- tibble(Time = as.POSIXct(c(
            '2020-01-06 00:22:15',
            '2020-01-06 00:45:16',    
            '2020-01-06 00:46:37',    
            '2020-01-06 01:29:55')), 
            Value = c(0,1,0,1))
```

and I want to plot something like [bar chart using time series and value data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPdLe.png)
Please see attachment as I can't add inline images yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the use of `geom_rect` from `ggplot2`. To prepared your tibble for the plotting, you can create a column used for setting the xmax that will correspond to the sequential time.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
z %>% mutate(xmax = lead(Time), y = 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(xmin = Time, xmax = xmax, ymin = y, ymax =y+1))+
  geom_rect(aes(fill = as.factor(Value)))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!